# google private service connect for cloudcomposer cloudSQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-sql

we are using google cloud cloudcomposer on one of the projects with its own VPC and cloudSQL database is on another project which is using a shared VPC from another project.

Is it possible for cloudcomposer to be able to privately connect to google cloudSQL and how?

[image]

update:

I have now setup VPC peering between cloudcomposer VPC and shared VPC. I spun up a VM on cloudcompose VPC test,
However cloudSQL auth proxy cannot reach cloudSQL DB.

```
kshk@test-instance-1:~$ ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=mgcp-xxxx-xxxx-pay-svc-sbx:europe-west2:xxxx-sbx-postgres=tcp:3307 -credential_file=access-1.json -ip_address_types=PRIVATE &

   kshk@test-instance-1:~$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 3307 -U testuser postgres
        2022/11/15 16:06:53 New connection for "mgcp-xxxx-xcxx-pay-svc-sbx:europe-west2:xxxxx-sbx-postgres"
        2022/11/15 16:06:53 refreshing ephemeral certificate for instance mgcp-xxxx-xxxx-pay-svc-sbx:europe-west2:xxxx-sbx-postgres
        2022/11/15 16:06:53 Scheduling refresh of ephemeral certificate in 54m59
        
        2022/11/15 16:09:04 couldn't connect to "mgcp-xxxx-xxx-pay-svc-sbx:europe-west2:xxxxx-sbx-postgres": dial tcp 10.12.121.5:3307: connect: connection timed out
        psql: error: server closed the connection unexpectedly
                This probably means the server terminated abnormally
                before or while processing the request.
```

Comment: Did you mean this use case mentioned here?: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/private-ip#cloud-sql If that is the case here are the steps on how to configure private IP environment for cloud comperser: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/configuring-private-ip Please be noted that the page is on cloud composer 1 tab, you can switch over by clicking cloud composer 2 if you are using the latter.

Comment: @NestorCenizaJr however cloudcomposer and cloudsql are on two different VPCs

Comment: If that is the case, I believe you are looking for VPC Peering, https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering, Alternatively you can consult this documentation for Private Service connect for Composer 2: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/configure-private-service-connect

Answer (score 3):

Because of [peering transitivity limitation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#restrictions), you can't achieve that. You have 2 solutions:

- Set up your Cloud Composer in your Shared VPC
- Set up a VPN (yes a VPN!) between the Composer VPC (default?) and the Shared VPC.

Comment: i have setup the VPC peering but getting timeout on cloudSQL PSC ip? any idea? updated with error on post...